# Leaflet custom edit ?handler?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet-draw

Is it possible to change the rectangle shown in edit mode to something else, like a marker, circle or an icon?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the marker with css like:

```
.leaflet-editing-icon {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #ffbf4b;
}
```

Else the draw plugin [Leaflet-Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman) is very nice and have modern vertex markers.